# Javascript: element size change handler (not css)

Tags: javascript, html

There is a div, which has styles:

```
min-width:100px
min-height:100px
```

When I add some text to the div(using JavaScript), it changes its size. How to get the new size?

I tried

```
element.offsetHeight
```

But it doesn't work as expected. I get size larger then I need in the first time. But after some time, if I get value of this propetry again, I get real size.

Maybe it's because there is some time between setting a text and fitting it into a div? I don't know.

```
<div class="parent"><div class="popup"></div></div>
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing:border-box;
  }
  .parent {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 0;
  }
  .popup {
    position: absolute;
    min-width: 100px;
    min-height: 100px;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 12px;
    background:#000;
    color:#fff;
    visibility:hidden;
  }
  .popup:before, .popup::before, .popup:after, .popup::after {
    content:"";
    width:0px;
    height:0px;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
  }
</style>
<script>
  var popup = document.getElementsByClassName('popup')[0];
  popup.innerHTML = 'любой текст от 3 до NNN строк';
  console.log(popup.offsetHeight);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the borders of the element, top, bottom, right and left and then subtract them in order to get the width and the height.  This accounts for the actual pixels on the page after it has been modified:

```
var width  = [element].getBoundingClientRect().right - [element].getBoundingClientRect().left ;
var height = [element].getBoundingClientRect().bottom - [element].getBoundingClientRect().top ;
```

Comment: I tried, but I have the same result. Firstly, size is bigger than after some time.

Comment: When doing those width or height computations from right-left or bottom-top, remember to add 1.

Comment: No, in my case, I just have 207, for example (for a long text) and then after some time, I got 137.

Answer (score 0):

Change this in your script. Notice that I added more text in innerHTML.

```
<script>
  var popup = document.getElementsByClassName('popup')[0];
  console.log("Before: "+popup.offsetHeight);
  popup.innerHTML = 'любой текст от 3 до NNN строк<br><br>moretext';
  console.log("After: "+popup.offsetHeight);
</script>
```

And change in your CSS the min-height to smaller value to see the difference

```
min-height:10px;
```

output in console is:

```
Before: 40
After: 180
```

Here is an example that works (open console to see the output): https://jsfiddle.net/_jserodio/q78dLz8h/

Comment: I have a DIV, not input or textarea. Change event doesn't work in this case.

Comment: Can you please post more code and/or explain why do you need that? Maybe there is another way to achieve what you are trying to do.

Comment: I need to get it height to do reposition. I added code but for some reason it works normally. I don't know (

Comment: I edited my first message, and added an example: https://jsfiddle.net/_jserodio/q78dLz8h/

Comment: Are you serious? document.getElementsByClassName('popup') returns an array of elements. And I'm changing contents of the element, not element itself.

Comment: add [0] to access the element, like you did previously in the first line. or you can document.querySelector(".popup").offsetHeight

Comment: I have the correct element, I'm NOT recreating it or something.

Comment: I have included your CSS and changed just one line, it is working now in my fiddle. (see first message again)

Comment: I was wrong earlier about getting the new value, but I noticed that if you were getting: 100 px always, is because your minimum is too large. But if you add a bigger text it should work. Not sure if you can decrease in your app your CSS but I am 100% sure that it works if you change: min-height:10px; and add couple <br> to the innerHTML...